# how to make django render the default home page instead of apache

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

As is known, after issuing a request with a sole IP or server name through web explorer, apache will return its default static home page to the explorer. I'm using django and apache with mod_wsgi to deploy my site(i.e. django app on apache web server). How to route the processing to django mapping rules defined in views.py to dynamically produce a home page(i.e. index page) for that site when I issue a request to that server running apache? Thanks in advance!

I added the following configuration in the main Apache 'httpd.conf':

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>

    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    ServerAlias example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com

    DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/documents

    Alias /robots.txt /usr/local/www/documents/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /usr/local/www/documents/favicon.ico

    Alias /media/ /usr/local/www/documents/media/

    <Directory /usr/local/www/documents>
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess 127.0.0.1 processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup 127.0.0.1

    WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi

    <Directory /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Code in myapp.wsgi:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = b'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

Then I issued 127.0.0.1, the explorer displayed 'It works!', which is the default page produced by apache, instead of which I wanted 'Hello world!' returned in this case. I just want that when just issued an IP or site address, the work of generating the default home page is directly delegated to django to dynamically handle rather than to return a static index.html by Apache. Although I configured `WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi` , this seems still not work.

Comment: No, it is not *known*. It doesn't serve the "default static home page" unless you specifically ask it to. How did you configure mod_wsgi in the first place?

Comment: As @DanielRoseman asks, supply the configuration you are using. If you have added ``WSGIScriptAlias / /some/path/to/wsgi.py`` and appropriate other config to enable access to that resource in the appropriate place, that should result in the WSGI application taking over requests for root of the site. If it isn't, then you likely have mucked up virtual host configuration.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton The configuration and necessary infomation have been supplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtual hosts don't work in that way for 127.0.0.1 as it is treated a bit special. What is going to happen, unless that is the only `VirtualHost` in your configuration, is that Apache will fall back to using the first `VirtualHost` definition it found, usually the default site.

So normally you would have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.fqdn.host.name
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

That is, no IP in `VirtualHost` directive and `ServerName` is the actual hostname that appears in the URL, not an IP address.

Was there a prior `VirtualHost` in `httpd.conf` or was it including including `extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`, that would result in a `VirtualHost` superseding this one?